# embedded pdf in excel sheet looks fuzzy and resized

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I have a pdf embedded in an excel  sheet but somehow thru the embedding  process the object becomes fuzzy and blurry.. 
Please help

Answer (score 1):

The PDF image you see embedded in your Excel spreadsheet sounds like a rasterized thumbnail.

PDF documents typically contain scalable vector graphics. Rasterizing a vector image converts it to a bitmap, an image represented by a sequence of dots. Bitmap images look blocky when scaled. Bitmap compression and resampling can decrease the image quality further.

Excel does not natively support the display of PDF images, AFAIK.  To display the PDF inside a spreadsheet you will need to convert it to a format understood by Excel.

Try converting the PDF document to an EMF or WMF file. These formats are capable of storing vector information and are most likely supported by Excel. Another format that might possibly work is SVG.

You should find applications available that will perform the conversion for you, although the conversion quality often seems poor in my experience.

If you wish to maintain the quality and functionality of the original PDF, you will need to link to the PDF document instead of embedding it.

Answer (score 0):

MS Office does not recognize PDF format for embedding, but one can attach the PDF as a link:

1. In Excel, under the Insert menu
   click on 'Object'. A new Object dialog window appears.
2. Choose Create from File
3. Browse to the PDF
4. Tick the boxes "Link to file" and "Display as icon"
5. Press OK